# Resource leaking of available PIDs by long running bash scripts

Tags: bash, scripting, memory-leaks

I am currently reading up on some more details on Bash scripting and especially process management [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement). In the section on "PIDs and Parents" I found the following statement:

> A process's PID will NEVER be freed up for use after the process dies UNTIL the parent process waits for the PID to see whether it ended and retrieve its exit code.

So if I understand this correctly, if I start an process in a bash script, then the process terminates, that the PID cannot be used by any other process. Wouldn't this mean, that if I have a long running script, which repeatedly starts other sub-processes but never waits on them, that I'll eventually have a resource leak, because the used PIDs will not be returned back to the system?

How about if I actually `wait` for the other process, but the `wait` get's cancelled by a trap. Would this wait somehow still free up the PID, or do I have to wait again after the trap has been caught?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily you won't. I can't tell you exactly why but you can easily test this. Run the following script (stop with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    sleep 5 &
    sleep 1
done
```

You can see you get no [zombies](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_display_and_kill_zombie_processes) (leaked PIDs) after 6+ seconds. To see some zombies use the following python code (again, stop with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, time

pl = []
while True:
    pl.append(subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "5"]))
    time.sleep(1)
```

After 6 seconds you'll see one zombie:

```
ps xaw | grep 'sleep'
...
26470 pts/2    Z+     0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
...
```

My guess is that bash does [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) and stores the results reaping the zombile processes with or without the builtin wait command. For the python script, if you remove the `pl.append` part the garbage collection releases the objects and does it's magic again reaping the zombies. Just for info a child may never become a zombie (from wikipedia, [Zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)):

> ...if the parent explicitly ignores SIGCHLD by setting its handler to SIG_IGN (rather
>   than simply ignoring the signal by default) or has the SA_NOCLDWAIT flag set, all
>   child exit status information will be discarded and no zombie processes will be left.

Comment: Yes, sure, if you ctrl-c out of the running script the children will be passed on to the init process, which then correctly `wait`'s on them and thus reaps the zombies. But the question was about a script which keeps on running for a long time. I think the wikipedia article also agrees that this is bad behaviour and may deplete the process id pool. ("The parent can read the child's exit status by executing the wait system call, whereupon the zombie is removed."). I'll still have to figure out the part about the cancelled wait though.

Comment: Before you press `Ctrl+C` you'll see the zombies, not after. `Ctrl+C` is just the way to stop the script after you are done testing. The 6 seconds was just a minimum, wait a minute and check, then kill with `Ctrl+C`. AFAIR the zombies are passed to your terminal (bash/zsh) and then to it's parent and so on and to init in the very end.

Comment: Ok, so I was correct. In this case a long running script will create zombies when it keeps starting new jobs and never waits for them.

Comment: No, you won't (I did not). You can see them from the python script. The whole purpose of the python script was to demonstrate how to check for zombies. The bash script did not show any zombies. Do you see zombies from the shell(bash) script?

Comment: On the system I tried this, I did see zombies. A coworker didn't. Also the test with the `sleep 10 & read` worked for me (i.e. created zombies) but not for Dennis below. I now have a new system and here both examples do not create zombies, so I really guess there is something configuration/version etc depended involved. Unfortunately I don't have access to the old system anymore, so I cannot check for differences in configuration. I'll post another note in case I ever find a system again, which has this behavior and figure out what the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly wait on foreground processes because the shell in which your script is running waits on them. The next process won't start until the previous one finishes.

If you start many long running *background* processes, you could use all available PIDs, but that's subject to the limit of `ulimit -u` (which could be unlimited).

Comment: Well, of course when I start the processes in the foreground then the shell automatically waits and there is no issue, so of course the question would not make sense. But I was referring to background processes, since that is what the `wait` builtin is meant for.

Comment: @LiKao: If a background process completes, its PID is available again just as if it were a foreground process. It's only processes that haven't completed that occupy a PID.

Comment: Hmm, then now I am entirely confused what a so called "zombie process" (as mentioned above, thanks for the hint) is and where it comes from. Just tried it myself with a small script (`sleep 10 & read`) and once the sleep terminates it is still displayed by `ps` as a defunct process. So when and how will it get cleared actually?

Comment: @LiKao: On my system, the `sleep` no longer appears in the process list once it completes and the `read` is holding the script in a running state.

Comment: Ok, then now I am utterly confused. I guess I'll have to do some very thorough reading up on processes and process handling in Unix over the weekend and then I'll come back to this issue. On my system I could clearly see the sleep even after I waited for some minutes. Maybe there is some configuration which sets up how this is handled.